# AddEventListener() is running even after control goes off-focus

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keyup

Here is My js code

```
function labal2(e, lbl) {
  console.log("hello")
  lbl.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if(event.which === 13){
      console.log("enter key pressed")
      return
    }
  })
}
```

here is my HTML

```
<body>
 <label contenteditable="true" onClick="labal2(event,this)">Hello</label>
</body>
```

when I click on label it goes to that listener, content is editable so I can edit the label 
when I click enter in my editable label it prints "enter is clicked"
Fine

**But after that if I goes off-focus form label means I click somewhere else in the window and after that, if I come again to label and press enter in that editable label it prints "enter key pressed" 2 times but I want 1 time only**

so whenever I go off-focus and come back to label and press enter that much time it prints "enter key pressed"

so if I go 3-time off-focus and came to label and press enter then it will print 4 times "enter key pressed"

**But when i put event.stopImmediatePropagation() after console log it behaves perfectly for me**

means no matter how much time I go off-focus to label when I click enter "enter key pressed" is print only one time
this is what I want

**but I didn't understand why and how this works?**

I am a beginner in js need some help, please let me know if I am going wrong somewhere

Comment: Never add an eventlistener in something that can be called more than once

Comment: Because youre adding another keyup listener every time you click on the element?

Comment: Add it once on window.onload or simply do `<label contenteditable="true" onkeyup="labal2(event,this)">Hello</label>` and do your keyup thing in the labal2 function

Comment: You are creating two event listeners `onClick` one in the html and one inside the function. either remove the one from the function, or create the event listener when the document loads.

Comment: @LukaKostic oh I got it thanks, so when I click the label second time it registers listener on the same label second time (so total 2 listeners on the same label) so that why event.stopImmediatePropagation() works right?

Comment: Yep, it stops the event at the first keypress, not allowing it to reach the second one.